# css3 div slower speed inside container

Tags: css, parallax

I have some javascript that gives the effect of text inside my banner scrolling slower and disappearing as the bottom of the banner scrolls up to meet it.

```
function scrollBanner() {
  //Get the scoll position of the page
  scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();

  //Scroll and fade out the banner text
  $('#bannerText').css({
    'margin-bottom' : -(scrollPos/3)+"px",
    'opacity' : 1-(scrollPos/300)
  });

}
```

I am now trying to achieve this with css3 as this way does not work with mobile for many reasons.

I have tried and failed with css translate. The text will scroll in the div but the page does not. Or I can scroll the page and the text stays lock in it positions and doesn't scroll at a slower speed.

CSS

```
.banner .parallax {
  perspective: 1px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 440px;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
}

.banner .parallax .parallax-container{
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%) translateZ(-2px) scale(1);
}
```

HTML

```
<section class="banner features-banner">
    <div class="banner-inner parallax">
        <div class="parallax-container">
            <h1 class="feature-primary-heading">FEATURE TOUR</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```